# Spock Test Failing with MissingPropertyException

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have a simple class that builds a `RequestMessage` based on a simple rule.

- If `MessageMetadata` is found in the database, the message is built using that metadata.
- Otherwise, the message is built using a service that provides the metadata.

Here is the class along with a Spock test. The test fails with a `MissingPropertyException`, saying it cannot find the `RequestMessage` created using the service.

```
class MessageService{
    MessageBuilder messageBuilder;
    MessageRepository messageRepository;
    MessageMetadaProvider messageMetaDataProvider;

    public RequestMessage getMessage(String id ) {
        try {
            MessageMetadata metadata = repository.findDefaulMessage(id);
            RequestMessage requestMessage = builder.createMessage(metadata);
            return requestMessage;
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MessageMetadata metadata = messageMetaDataProvider.createNewMessageMetadata(id);
        RequestMessage message = messageBuilder.buildNew(id , metadata);
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
def "Build Request Message  "() {
    given:
    String id = '12345'
    MessageBuilder messageBuilder = Mock()
    MessageRepository messageRepository = Mock()
    MessageMetadaProvider messageMetaDataProvider = Mock()
    MessageService service = createMessageService(messageRepository,messageBuilder,messageMetaDataProvider)
    MessageMetadata metadata = new MessageMedata(id, MessageType.DEFAULT)
    when:
    RequestMessage requestMessage = messageService .getMessage(id )
    then:
    1 * messageRepository.repository.findDefaulMessage(id) >> {throw new DataNotFoundException("Not Found")}
    1 * messageMetaDataProvider.createNewMessageMetadata(id) >> metadata
    1  *  messageBuilder.buildNew(id , metadata) >> requestMessage
}
```

I would really like to understand why this doesn't work. I'm grateful for any help in testing this test successfully. Thank you

Comment: Your code with your many dependency classes does not constitute an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Furthermore, there is inconsistency in your sample class, e.g. `messageBuilder` vs. `builder` and `messageRepository` vs. `repository`. Then in your test there is `messageRepository.repository` as if the `messageRepository` had a property or a getter also named `repository` which would at least be strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed the hen vs. egg problem I mentioned in my comment to *jaco0646*'s answer. Let me recreate the core problem in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388;

public class RequestMessage {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388;

public class MessageService {
  MessageBuilder messageBuilder;

  public RequestMessage getMessage(String id) {
    return messageBuilder.buildNew(id);
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388

import spock.lang.Specification

class MessageServiceTest extends Specification {
  def "build request message"() {
    given:
    def id = "12345"
    MessageBuilder messageBuilder = Mock()
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService()
    messageService.messageBuilder = messageBuilder

    when:
    RequestMessage requestMessage = messageService.getMessage(id)

    then:
    1 * messageBuilder.buildNew(id) >> requestMessage
  }
}
```

This will yield:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: requestMessage for class: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388.MessageServiceTest

    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388.MessageServiceTest.build request message(MessageServiceTest.groovy:17)
```

Just declaring `requestMessage` in the `given:` block as *jaco0646* suggested and then using it as a stub result won't do it alone. You need to make sure that you first declare an object (e.g. a mock) to be returned by the builder method, but assign the result of the method call under test to another variable so you can compare the two or do whatever verification you like to perform:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60143388

import spock.lang.Specification

class MessageServiceTest extends Specification {
  def "build request message"() {
    given:
    def id = "12345"
    RequestMessage requestMessage = Mock()
    MessageBuilder messageBuilder = Mock()
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService()
    messageService.messageBuilder = messageBuilder

    when:
    RequestMessage result = messageService.getMessage(id)

    then:
    1 * messageBuilder.buildNew(id) >> requestMessage
    result.toString().startsWith("Mock for type 'RequestMessage'")
  }
}
```

Now the test passes and your bootstrapping problem is solved. You cannot create an object with a method call and then specify it as an expected stub result at the same time. It makes no logical sense.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I really do appreciate this, it works as you specified. Thanks for all the other suggestions, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `requestMessage` in the `given` block rather than the `when` block.

The Spock [lifecycle](https://gist.github.com/jaco0646/6347541de3591bf8845a4a837b5dcdae) has some surprising behaviors, one of which is that [interactions](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#_interactions) are processed *before* the `when` block.

Comment: Could you maybe explain better what the problem is and provide an example, not just say "try this". Maybe you are right, but I don't understand your explanation. Are you maybe referring to the situation that the OP wants to create a stub returning `requestMessage` in `buildNew()` before actually creating the `requestMessage` in the `when:` block, which would be a kind of hen vs. egg problem?